# Two QListView's and a multimensional array, one showing the array of the selected element

Tags: c++, qt, qlistview, qabstracttablemodel

Having trouble with the title of the question but essentially I have a two `QListView`'s side by side, a two dimensional array and using a `TableViewModel` containing that array;   and now I want the `QListView` on the right to display the selected row's array. Is this actually possible?

Comment: Of course this is possible. For instance you could connect the first widgets [clicked signal](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#clicked) to a custom slot where you clear and populate the second widget based on the index received by the signal.

Comment: Wouldn't that require another model for the second widget?